# SQL Server hierarchical find all managers for manager and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have an employee table that includes `EmployeeId` and `ManagerId`. I'm trying to do a hierarchical query and find all managers that are under a specific manager even if they are not direct reports.

So far I created this query

```sql
WITH cte_org AS 
(
    SELECT       
        EmployeeId,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        ManagerEID
    FROM       
        Users
    WHERE  
        ManagerEID = @ManagerEID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        u.EmployeeId,
        u.FirstName,
        u.LastName,
        u.ManagerEID
    FROM 
        Users u
    INNER JOIN 
        cte_org o ON o.EmployeeId = u.ManagerEID
)
SELECT DISTINCT(ManagerEID)
FROM cte_org
WHERE ManagerEID != @ManagerEID;
```

This query works fine, in this specific scenario I'm selecting 13 rows.

The problem is that I want to insert these rows into a new table that has some other columns I need to populate. So I attempted to do this instead:

```sql
WITH cte_org AS 
(
    SELECT       
        EmployeeId,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        ManagerEID
    FROM       
        Users
    WHERE 
        ManagerEID = @ManagerEID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        u.EmployeeId,
        u.FirstName,
        u.LastName,
        u.ManagerEID
    FROM 
        Users u
    INNER JOIN 
        cte_org o ON o.EmployeeId = u.ManagerEID
)
INSERT INTO TeamRoles (ManagerEID, Id, TeamName, IsTopLevel, IsRecursive, TopLevelManagerEID, RoleId)
    SELECT DISTINCT(ManagerEID), NEWID(), 'Static VALUE', 0, 1, @ManagerEID, 4
    FROM cte_org
    WHERE ManagerEID != @MangerEID;
```

Now this query is inserting 33 rows.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this query/insert?

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected result

Comment: I suspect that in the original query you have multiple users with identical managers. Since you’re doing DISTINCT() ON ManagerEID, you’re removing those duplicates. If you remove the distinct, you can see the entire list… you’ll need to cleanup your where statement to something more distinct

Comment: Yes I'm finding all employees that are under a specific manager then doing a distinct to get the distinct managers.  Any ideas on how to implement your suggestion?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it basically means `GROUP BY` every column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more new CTE table, then use the new CTE table to process insert.

```
WITH cte_org AS (
SELECT       
    EmployeeId,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    ManagerEID
FROM       
    Users
WHERE ManagerEID = @ManagerEID
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    u.EmployeeId,
    u.FirstName,
    u.LastName,
    u.ManagerEID
FROM 
    Users u
    INNER JOIN cte_org o 
        ON o.EmployeeId = u.ManagerEID
),
cte_org_new
AS
(
    SELECT distinct(ManagerEID)
    from cte_org
    where ManagerEID != @ManagerEID;    
)

INSERT Into TeamRoles(ManagerEID, Id, TeamName, IsTopLevel, IsRecursive, TopLevelManagerEID, RoleId)
SELECT ManagerEID, NEWID(), 'Static VALUE', 0, 1, @ManagerEID, 4
FROM cte_org_new
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original query, you had only managerId and your distinct removed duplicates.

In your subsequent insert query, as you are having NEWID(), every row is unique. So, your DISTINCT is not filtering duplicate ManagerId.

I am having simple code below to explain your scenario.

```sql
declare @TABLE Table(ManagerId int)

insert into @Table
values (1),(1),(1)

SELECT DISTINCT(managerid), newid() as id from @table
```

| managerid | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 401845D6-BA6F-4BE2-9200-171A24BDCFB8 |
| 1 | 8A54A569-DC87-4FD9-A05A-55AAF40E4F35 |
| 1 | 46C789BD-E5F3-458A-9EFA-B5B63621F189 |

What you have to do is,

```sql
 INSERT Into TeamRoles(ManagerEID, Id, TeamName, IsTopLevel, IsRecursive, TopLevelManagerEID, RoleId)

SELECT ManagerEID    , NEWID(), 'Static VALUE', 0, 1, @ManagerEID, 4
FROM
    (SELECT distinct(ManagerEID)
    FROM cte_org
    WHERE ManagerEID != @MangerEID) as t
```